# Controlling navmesh agent rotation resulting in odd behavior

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a navmesh agent, I was not happy with how it updated its rotation (was always slightly off), so I turned it off and did it my self.

It works really nicely, however when I run the game at 3-4 times the speed (management game), they will sometimes lay down flat for 0,5-1 seconds then keep going, I'm assuming it's caused by this script.

Im pretty sure its when they are standing still or just about to turn.

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    if (agent.velocity.sqrMagnitude > Mathf.Epsilon)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(agent.velocity.normalized);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was happening while calculating a path, so adding this solved it:

```
 void LateUpdate()
{
    if (agent.hasPath)
    {
        if (agent.velocity.sqrMagnitude > Mathf.Epsilon)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(agent.velocity.normalized);
        }
    }
}
```